# Create user in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions

I have SQL Server user in the database and for some reason, user is not able to  view the tables when connecting

Here are the commands that I am using to create that user.  I do not want to make the user `dbuser` the owner of the schema.

```
create user dbuser for login dbuser'

--on the specific database, I am using these commands.
exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_datareader', @membername = 'dbuser'
exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_datawriter', @membername = 'dbuser'

grant select on schema :: [schema1] TO [dbuser]
grant insert on schema  :: [schema1] TO [dbuser]
grant update  on schema :: [schema1] TO [dbuser]
grant execute  on schema  :: [schema1] TO [dbuser]

grant select on schema :: [schema2] TO [dbuser]
grant insert on schema  :: [schema2] TO [dbuser]
grant update  on schema  :: [schema2] TO [dbuser]
grant execute  on schema  :: [schema2] TO [dbuser]
```

Even though I am granting all insert and update access on the schema.. the user when logged in with `dbuser` is not able to view the any of the tables from any of the schema. He just sees the system tables tab when the user tries to connect to the database. User needs to see all the tables under the `schema1,schema2, schema3`

thanks

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thank you for editing it for me. I will do it here on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a workaround found at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/387616/tables-node-does-not-show-all-schemas-in-ssmse-2008)

do the following:

> To resolve the issue, you must login as an Administrator, right-click
>   the Database node, choose Properties, Permissions, and grant the "View
>   definition" permission to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the user is connecting to your db and not master?  And that you are creating the user in the right DB?

Comment: Yes I am i see the user created, in the db that i wished to create this user.

Comment: @pkat: are you sure that user isn't DENYd somewhere?  I just tested your code, and it worked for me with the dbo schema.  The only thing I changed is the single quote after your create user for login (deleted it), and the schema names.  Also, you probably don't need to add any of the rights explicitly, as the addrolemember should take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the above answer.

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[schema1] TO [dbuser];
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[schema2] TO [dbuser];
```

Comment: intrestingly, this didnt work,I added this to my script and ran, it was still the same issue. But when I followed, NCGrimbo, it worked.